# jnlp lazy jar downloading not being respected

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm wanting to support the lazy downloading of jars in my webstart application, but can't get it to work.

From reading the doc, all I need to do is add a `download="lazy"` attribute to my jar element. And this is how I did it:

```xml
<jar href="lib/bigjar.jar" download="lazy"/>
```

But when it starts, I can see from the Cache Viewer that it has been loaded, despite the class definitely not being used at that point (I verified this by removing the jar and the app starts properly, as expected).

I have read several posts, and there appears to be several ideas of things that prevent lazy downloading, despite these not being documented to my knowledge. So, here is my status on the things I've read:

1. I'm using signed jars
2. I'm not using an index in the jars
3. I'm pack200 some of the jars
4. I'm not declaring any "parts"

Does anyone know if these things definitely prevent lazy downloading? Or have any other ideas about why it is not working?

Comment: Definitely use indexing, and I strongly recommend using parts.  Note though that even importing a class from the Jar into other code that is downloaded can trigger the download of the 'lazy' Jar..  It is quite tricky to get it working as expected.